# Why does my wbemservices execquery work when I run from command prompt, but triggers an access violation when run as a service?

Tags: wbem

I have a query that gets a list of the running processes so I can monitor some of them.  When I run my software from the command prompt it works just fine, but when I install it as a service I get an access violation. On the exec query call.

I would have expected the program running as a service to behave like the program running from command line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you explain more about the problem in detail? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am using wbemservices ExecQuery inside a C++ program to get a list of processes running on the local machine.  The coinitialize and coinitializesecurity are setup.  The program I am creating will need to run installed on the machine as a service.  When I run the program from command line it works just fine, when I install the program as a service (using sc.exe) and start it.  Then I get an access violation error.  It does not notify me of anything.  The program just disappears.  I know it is an access violation because I have attached visual studio debugger to the program.